# Symfony timeline/wall implementation

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, timeline

Is there any existing bundle for symfony2 that has some kind of wall Facebook or Twitter like where users have an input for text/images/videos and a chronological list with all inputs.

I found: timeline-bundle by stephy on github but inputting is by several inputs (verb, subject, etc.) and I need single text input only(Twitter like).

Also found sonata-timeline which implements timeline-bundle.

Answer (score 0):

a really well done solution is FOSCommentBundle